# 2 words HAD in a row

Tags: past-perfect

I don't understand this sentence, what are two words "HAD" mean?

> "I think they may have thought that reaching out to people who represent what is now the mainstream way of thinking and HAD who HAD more access to the Trump administration than people in past was a better way to send messages or get information," said Bruce Klingner.
>
> [CNN](http://edition.cnn.com/2017/09/28/politics/north-korea-trump-republicans-outreach/index.html) — (beware the autoplay video)

Comment: I think "had who had" is a typo remaining after indecision whether to write "who had" or "had had". But you might like to [read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_while_John_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_a_better_effect_on_the_teacher) about multiple **had**.

Comment: Typo? I thought so at first , but why not just word "HAVE"? Present tense is more appropriate in this context I think

Comment: "may have thought" is past tense. "have" is present tense.

Comment: It’s a quote which contains (self-) corrected speech. The first *had* can be ignored. Cf @Weather’s comment.

Comment: Dear Clare, are you sure it's self-correction by Mr. Clinger?

Comment: Weather Vane , "may have thought " is present ( perfect) tense, not past tense

Comment: @KossM it is punctuated as a direct quote of the speaker's words, so that is what any reader should assume.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is almost certainly predicated on a typo.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly a typo in the article or an error on the part of the person being quoted. The first "had" should have been omitted.